# SwiftUI LazyHStack inside LazyVStack layout issues

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `LazyHStack` inside a `LazyVStack` which renders poorly. The code and screenshot are below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let data = (1...20).map { "Item \($0)" }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                        LazyHStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Text("Column 1")
                            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                Text("Column 2, Row 1")
                                Text("Column 2, Row 2")
                            }
                            Text("Column 3")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If I change the `LazyHStack` to a `HStack` it works as below:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can achieve this with a `LazyHStack`?

Comment: You don't need LazyHStack here, because *lazy-ness* is needed for ScrollView, and it handles only top-level lazy container to load content, everything else is redundant. So I recommend to keep HStack.

Comment: i've dealt with it, my solution is also use only lazy once on the very top